# Cross Entropy Loss Pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, image-segmentation, loss-function

I have a question regarding an optimal implementation of Cross Entropy Loss in my pytorch - network. I am building a network that predicts 3D-Segmentations of Volume-Pictures. I have either background class or one foreground class, but it should have the possibility to also predict two or more different foreground classes.

The input into my network when training is of the shape [batch_size, input_channels, width, height, depth]. Input channels is equal to one since I only have greyscale images and depth is according to the number of 2D pictures that make up the 3D volume.

The output of the network is [batch_size, #classes, width, height, depth]. #classes is equal to two right now and the two dimensions are pretty much just the inverse of one another since I only have the background class and one foreground class right now.

Now I want to compute the cross entropy loss. Right now my implementation looks like this:

```
    def loss(output, gt):
    loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    gt_temp = torch.tensor(np.zeros((output.shape[0], output.shape[2],output.shape[3], output.shape[4]))).long()
    gt_temp[:, :, :, :] = gt[:, 0, :, :, :]
    return loss_fn(output, gt_temp)
```

I have to do some dimension changes with the groundtruth since nn.CrossEntropyLoss() expects the groundtruth to be of size (5, 384, 384, 81), while the output is of size (5, 2, 384, 384, 81)
--> batch_size = 5, #classes = 2, picture = 384x384 and 81 pictures deep.

The problem is that this isn't really working. It converges to a loss of 0.5-0.6 and it just predicts the whole output to be background. What should I do?

It would be awesome if someone could help!!! Also I dont understand why output and groundtruth shouldn't be of the same shape ?!

Thanks!

Comment: Please refer to [focal loss](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002) which is designed to solve problems like this, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Regarding the shape problem: not possible to help without proper code and stack trace.

Comment: what is your label's shape?

Comment: shape of groundtruth as well as predicitions are (#batches, #classes, width, height, depth)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the shape question,there are two pytorch loss functions for cross entropy loss:

1. Binary Cross Entropy Loss - expects each target and output to be a tensor of shape [batch_size, num_classes, ....], each with a value in the range [0,1].
2. Cross Entropy Loss - for simplicity, the target tensor is instead of size [batch_size,...]. each with an integer value in the range [0,num_classes - 1].

It may be helpful to think that the first thing done in the Cross Entropy Loss function is to use the target tensor to compute the target tensor for Binary Cross Entropy Loss, and then loss is computed the same way as in this loss function. The only difference is that depending on how your target data is formatted, one or the other formulation may be slightly more convenient as it will require less reshaping.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am trying to run my network with BCELoss and see what'll happen